# Automatically resize image with column width

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to automatically resize an image so that it's width is that of a certain column range, say column A to J in Excel.

The image is a banner image that spans the width of the page on a quotation.
I would like it's width to change as the column widths change so the width of the image always coincides with the width of column A to J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need VBA for this.

To make the control stay with a cell when the cell moves (for example, when it is sorted) and to resize the control when the cell height and width changes, select **Move and size with cells**.

1. Right-click the selection, click Format Control, and then click the Properties tab.
2. Under Object Positioning, make sure **Move and size with cells** is selected.

See also [Position and size a control with its underlying cell on a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Position-and-size-a-control-with-its-underlying-cell-on-a-worksheet-f91032aa-b245-41e3-b296-9d13104af484).

Comment: Would this be possible for the Picture to move with multiple cells? What I had read online was about resizing the picture to fit a cell.I have the picture across the top of the sheet as a wide banner, and sometimes the column widths change, depending on the values in them. I wanted the pictures width to always be to the end of column J

Comment: Yes, it does. Why don't you just try it? If you change the width of any column under the image, the image will automatically resize.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no `Worksheet_CellSizeChange` or any other comparable event avaiable in Excel. However, you could use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to autofit your picture whenever you select another cell. Just paste the code in the regarding worksheet in Visual Basic Editor:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Me.Columns("A:J")

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, myRange) Is Nothing Then
        If Not Me.Pictures(1).Width = myRange.Columns.Width Then
            Me.Pictures(1).Width = myRange.Columns.Width
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```